# proper usage of forms with routes in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

i have this form in view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'StudentrecordController@viewSRS')) }}
    <span><strong>Select School Year & Quarter</strong></span>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::select('sy', [null=> 'Select School Year'] + $schoolYearID , Input::old('modules'), array('class'=>'form-control') ) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::select('sq', [null=> 'Select Quarter'] + $schoolQuarterID , Input::old('modules'), array('class'=>'form-control') ) }}
    </div>
    {{ Form::submit('Sort', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

my route for this is

```
Route::get('sortsRec', 'StudentrecordController@viewSRS');
```

when i clicked the submit button it gives out a method not allowed exception.i think the form is sending out a post method but the route accepts get. how can i address this? any idea what i can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a `POST` method will be assumed; however, you are free to specify another method:

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'get', 'action' => 'StudentrecordController@viewSRS']) }}
```

From [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form).